# Stuck with MVVM declaration using knockout & upshot

Tags: singlepage, upshot, single-page-application

I have my service returinig data in this format
[image]

Now I am trying to access data in html this way
[image]

I am able to access the current period but not the Id of WebChartView.

BTW I am using MVC4 chartResult is the view Model

Comment: I assume you've tried setting it to `Result().Data().WebChartView().Id` What error does that give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Data Property is Collection of WebChartViews so I have tried like this 
    Result().Data() to loop through and it worked